# JSON encodes cyryllic as a null

Tags: php, mysql, json, cyrillic

I have MYSQL table with Cyrillic symbols.
[This is my MYSQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSsMx.png)

And i use PHP to get MYSQL result and encode it to JSON.

```
    <?php

include 'connection.php';

$array_to_json = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM online";


$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$row_array['parameters'] = $row['parameters'];

$row_array['Descriptions'] = $row['Descriptions'];

$row_array['units'] = $row['units'];
      array_push($array_to_json, $row_array);

}

echo json_encode($array_to_json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$result->close();

?>
```

And as a result i have got null.
[JSON returns null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuWOS.png)

What do i do wrong?

Comment: May be something wrong with a structure of a table?
http://prntscr.com/chu681

Comment: Please, use `var_dump($row_array);` to check that your data is being filled. If its not, then use  `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_general_ci'");` to check for an encode issue. Finally, do note that msql_* are deprecated, you should migrate to msqli_*

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using

```
    $row_array['parameters']    = base64_encode($row['parameters']);
    $row_array['Descriptions']  = base64_encode($row['Descriptions']);
    $row_array['units']         = base64_encode($row['units']);
    array_push($array_to_json, $row_array);
```

Comment: You may still have to decode those html characters back before using them... @Anton

Answer (score 0):

recheck your table structure and ensure that there is no extra blank space

for instance:

```
$row['Descriptions ']
```

instead of:

```
$row['Descriptions'];
```